# Alphabet range with num and item from list

Tags: python, string, list, alphabet

I have a list:

```
lst = ['cat', 'cow', 'dog']
```

Need to print:

```
A1 cat
B2 cow
C3 dog
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Read about loops and how to iterate over lists in Python. What did you try? What problems did you run into?

Comment: `print("A1 cat\nB2 cow\nC3 dog")` solves this particular case, but is probably not very well generalizable. What are the `A1`,...,`C3` strings, how do they depend on the names of the animals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
lst = ['cat', 'cow', 'dog']

for num, (letter, item) in enumerate(zip(ascii_uppercase, lst), 1):
    print('{0}{1} {2}'.format(letter, num, item))

# A1 cat
# B2 cow
# C3 dog
```

**Explanation**

- Use `enumerate` for a numeric counter with optional start value of 1.
- Use `string.ascii_uppercase` to loop upper case alphabet.
- `zip` and loop through, using `str.format` to format your output.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to use ASCII values of the alphabets and increment it over every iteration of the loop.

```
ascii_char_code = 65
lst = ['cat', 'cow', 'dog']

for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    print(chr(ascii_char_code) + str(index) + ' ' + item)
    ascii_char_code += 1
```

The **chr() function** converts ASCII code to the corresponding character

Comment: Interesting solution
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple `enumerate` approach :

```
lst = ['cat', 'cow', 'dog']

chr_s = list(map(chr,range(65,90)))

for i,j in enumerate(lst,1):
    print("{}{} {}".format(chr_s[i-1],i,j))
```

output:

```
A1 cat
B2 cow
C3 dog
```